# Insert Record if not exists using Python and SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a logic to "If record does not exists then insert record in table" using Python and SQL Server.

Below is my code:

```
InsertFileQuery = """
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[TABLE] F WHERE F.File = ? )
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[TABLE]([A] ,[file] ,[B],[C] ,[D] ,[E] ,[F])
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   END
END
                 """

values = (A, file, B, C, D, E, F)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(InsertFileQuery, values)
```

How should I pass `F.File = ?` into `values()`. So that, my code will see if record does not exists and then insert record.

Comment: `values = (file, A, file, B, C, D, E, F)` should do it.

Comment: You could use python string formatting in your `InsertFilterQuery` variable, so something like `"""blabla query F.file = '{0}' ...""".format(file)`

Comment: I am getting following error:   cursor.execute(InsertFileQuery, values)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Got it resolved using above @Vergil's approach

Comment: I recommend you using (pandas) library, it's handle such case easily and doing search for you too just by using function extremely fast. If you don't like then you can phrase sql statment using (sqlparser)
https://pypi.org/project/sqlparser/